# Passing an array of image objects to Fancybox (lightbox) doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I'm trying to get [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to display a series of images in a lightbox. Unfortunately, only the first image is showing up. As far as I can tell from [the docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs), I should be able to pass an array of objects to fancybox and have it open them all.

My code is below (note that I translated from coffeescript off the cuff so it might have some errors).

When I log the `images` array it seems like a perfectly normal array of objects. Navigating to the url for each image in the browser displays the image perfectly, proving that the URLs are valid.

```
$(function(){
  $('.lightbox').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // need to be able to get the link target
    $link = $(event.target).closest('a');

    $.getJSON($link.attr('href'), function(cake){
      // map the json to an array that fancybox can use
      images = $(cake.images).map(function(key, image)){
        return({ href: image.url });
      });

      console.log(images);
      // => [{href: 'image1.jpg'},{href: 'image2.jpg'},{href: 'image3.jpg'}]

      // show the lightbox
      $.fancybox.open(images);
    });
  });
});
```

HTML (with some ruby mixed in):

```
<a href="<%= cake_path(cake) %>" class="lightbox">
  <%= cake.primary_thumbnail %>
  <h2>Chocolate Cake</h2>
</a>
```

One other hint is that passing the option `index: 2` to fancybox breaks it (it should cause the script to open on the third image in the sequence). I get the following error:

```
475Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened [an issue on Github](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/83) and was told to update to the [latest version](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/zipball/master) (which is newer than the version currently available via the download link on the FancyBox website). The problem went away once I did that.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be:

```
$.fancybox([ 
 {href : 'img1.jpg', title : 'Title'}, 
 {href : 'img2.jpg', title : 'Title'},
 {href : 'img3.jpg', title : 'Title'}  
 ],[
 {
 // API options here
 }
]);
```

so I guess your constructor should return every array element followed by a comma except the last one:

```
{ href: image.url },
```

then I guess you should call fancybox like:

```
$.fancybox.open([images]);
```